# CloudSQL PostgreSQL Import Query ERROR Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am using CloudSQL PostgreSQL to BigQuery Data export using Cloud Data Fusion. Here is the simple import Query with table name "parameter".
[image]

But I am getting the ERROR about adding condition to Query. I don't think when we specify number of splits = 1 we don't need to specify anything in the Query but here:

```
Could not find the clause substitution token $CONDITIONS in the query: [SELECT * FROM parameters;]. Parallel splits may not work correctly.
```

How can I move data from Cloud SQL to BigQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this WHERE clause to the end of your query `WHERE $CONDITIONS`, worked for me.